# Using generic type as object index doesn't work. why? (ts2536)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to get an object value, it's dinamically accessed through the parameters of the function. One of these parameters I used a generic type to type it, but when I try to use it as a key, it gives this error "Type x cannot be used to index type y", even though the code works perfectly.

Here's an online environment in which you can see the error in question. It's in functions, in the end.

https://codesandbox.io/s/generic-type-indexing-khp21z?file=/src/files/functions.ts

or you can look to the specific part where the error happens below:

```js
const extendedFieldTextGetter = (
      field: T,
      subtitleToGet: keyof ExtendedLanguageFields[T]["subtitles"],
      subtitleValue: ContentOptions
    ) => {
      try {
        // ----> HERE <----
        const valueToReturn =
          extendedLanguageFieldsText[langcode][field]["subtitles"][
            subtitleToGet
          ][subtitleValue];

        return valueToReturn;
      } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof Error) {
          console.warn("Caught error on Extended Field Text Getter:");
          console.error(error.message);
        }
      }
    };
```

Since ***field*** is typed with a generic T, typescript complains about ts2536, the error I talked about before.

I tried many things with and without ChatGPT, but nothing worked. One of them that I think that should definitely work but didn't was trying to do this:

```
extendedLanguageFieldsText[langcode][field as keyof ExtendedLanguageFields]...
```

Why is it happening and/or how do I solve it?

Comment: Please [edit] to put your [mre] as plaintext within the body of the question itself; we can’t require people navigate away from Stack Overflow to see the code necessary to understand the issue.

Comment: The "minimal reproducible example" is already very big, that's why I put it in a external codesandbox environment. But ok, I'll try bringing it in.

Comment: Please review the guidelines for what constitutes a [mre]. If it's too big to fit here, it's almost certainly not minimal. In my experience almost all issues suitable for Stack Overflow can be demonstrated in a single screenful of text. Please work on cutting down the code so that it's a self-contained demonstration of your issue; anything not directly involved with the problem should be removed, and third-party/undeclared types/values should be replaced with native versions wherever possible. It takes work to do that, but that's part of the process for [ask]. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I tried again, just cut out what mattered from the code where the error happens. If it's still not good enough, I don't believe I'll be able to do what's needed to have my questoin answered, so feel free to close or delete it. Thanks for you kindness.

Comment: Given that [copying and pasting your code to another IDE](https://tsplay.dev/mA8jRN) results in a lot of errors unrelated to your question, it's unfortunately still not a [mre].  If you can't produce one, it's possible someone will come along and answer without needing it (or without needing it in the text of the question), but I'll disengage now.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use type guards and `Record` utility type to achieve what you want but you may need to update your existing types. I've updated your code, check it out and see if it works for you:

https://codesandbox.io/s/generic-type-indexing-forked-m7ct08?file=/src/files/functions.ts

here are the doc links:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type